# How to print common multiples of two number?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print all common multiples of two integers smaller than a certain limit(100 in my case). However, when I call my function, it does nothing. This is my code:

```
void com_mul(int a, int b)
{
    int original = b;

    for(int i = 1; a <= 100; i++)
    {
        a *= i;
        b = original;
        for(int j = 1; b <= a; j++)
        {
            b *= j;
            if(a == b)
                cout << b << ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're not using the iteration variable in either `for` loop, you might consider `while` loops instead. *Never mind, I'm blind.*

Comment: @BenN Hes using both iteration variables `a*=i` and `b*=j`. He could use a while loop but i think for loop is better for how he is attacking this problem

Comment: Oh whoops, I'm blind! Disregard my earlier comment, sorry. @JackV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with `a = 4, b = 2, max = 100` on my machine. And it outputs 4.
This is because of the line `for (int j = 1; b <= a; j++)`. `j` can only go upto 'a'

I think this would do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a, b, max;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> max;

    for (int i = a; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (i%a == 0 && i%b == 0)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem much simpler, using a single loop.

In a `for` loop iterate over potential divisors `d` from 1 to 100. If `d` divides both `a` and `b`, print `d`.

You can tell if a number divides another number by applying the `%` operator, and checking the result for zero:

```
if (a%d == 0 && b%d == 0) {
    cout << d << endl;
}
```